# Purpose of Content, Title and Keyword in semantic ranking

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, ranking, semantic-search

I am new to `semantic search`/`semantic ranking`. I might also be incorrectly using the words. I have few questions to understand the concept of semantic ranking, if someone could help.

1. Are Semantic search and Semantic ranking same?
2. In `Azure AI search`, when creating a search index which does semantic ranking, the configuration requires three fields - `title`, `content` and `keyword`. What is their purpose and how does semantic ranker uses them ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.prioritizedfields?view=azure-python-preview

Eventually, I  am trying to get answer to this question in which the search didn't return the right answer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.prioritizedfields?view=azure-python-preview

Comment: Regarding #2, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-how-to-query-request?tabs=portal%2Cportal-query#2---create-a-semantic-configuration. In general, semantic ranking is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-search-overview. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Semantic ranking was formerly named "semantic search". See [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/whats-new#:~:text=Semantic%20ranking%2C%20generally,for%20production%20workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/whats-new#:%7E:text=Semantic%20ranking%2C%20generally,for%20production%20workloads).

As part of the General Availability announcement, the product was renamed (likely to clarify the feature performs *reranking* of results)

The other comment has linked the correct page that explains the purpose of the three fields `title`, `content` and `keyword`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/semantic-how-to-query-request?tabs=portal%2Cportal-query#2---create-a-semantic-configuration)